# Request to reopen this question

Tags: discussion

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/64265/how-should-i-teach-people-how-to-treat-me-in-a-job-setting-when-im-just-a-new-c?noredirect=1#comment175627_64265

I have made some changes in it. Hope this is eligible to stay open on this community.

Comment: Still pretty long, why not summarise it into the core issue, which is 'How to stop people treating me like a kid and being disrespectful to my face.' or something like that....

Comment: @Kilisi Thanks. Wouldn't deleting some-more make it too vague or general for people to understand? I wrote the particular things to avoid being asked questions about particular things later. But never mind, I have deleted some fluff. Is it better now?

Comment: Many of us went through something similar in our youth, so perhaps that's why you're not getting much sympathy, because realistically there isn't a lot you can do without making it worse. You push back when you can, but mostly you just keep your head down and act professional until you gain respect.

Comment: I agree that it's too long.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want this reopened, I'd suggest following [Kilisi's advice](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3594/request-to-reopen-this-question#comment8743_3594). You could summarise your entire question into a variation of your last sentence:

> How should a newcomer to the workplace act to build a reputation as a dependable coworker and lose the "newbie" tag?

**The wall of text you give describing your situation confuses your post and detracts from your argument** because you're seeing belittlement and condescension when they probably aren't there. You *are* the new kid on the block. People are used to newcomers feeling overconfident or pretending to know the ins-and-outs of expensive equipment when they haven't even mastered the basics. 'Harmless' comments or jokes about age, appearance and body image are incredibly problematic and while society is becoming more aware of that they are still common.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I think the only answer is "take the chip off your shoulder, focus on simply *demonstrating* that you're a competent member of the team, accept that until someone else joins you're going to be 'the kid' and that there is nothing malicious about that nor anything to be embarrassed about, and recognise that *everyone* does a few minor tasks like helping with a trivial piece of equipment simply because friends do that for each other."

I'm not sure whether that makes this a usefully answerable question or not. I think so, but I don't think it's an answer the OP will appreciate.